# How to handle the responsive footer in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dom, layout

Here is the code of the footer

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <span class="copyright link">Copyright © 2006-2015 Pure International</span>
  <ul id="footer_nav" class="list-inline">
    <li><a class="link" href="<?= site_url("page/view/privacy"); ?>"><?= lang("privacy"); ?></a></li>|
    <li><a class="link" href="<?= site_url("page/view/terms"); ?>"><?= lang("t&c"); ?></a></li>|
    <li><a class="link" href="<?= site_url("page/view/about_us"); ?>"><?= lang("about_us"); ?></a></li>|
    <li><a class="link" href="<?= site_url("page/view/contact_us"); ?>"><?= lang("contact_us"); ?></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please have a look in the responsive behavior

At the beginning , it works fine
[image]

When it is ~690px. It become two lines and the contact us line has align right.This is the **1st** problem, how can it align left when it is .col-sm- (<750px)?
[image]

When it reduce to the smallest size , all text just stick together. This is the **2nd** problem , how can I show the item line by line when it is .col-xs (for smallest resolution)?
[image]

eg

```
Privacy Policy
Terms and Conditions
About Us
Contact Us
```

It is perfer to fix by bootstrap tag but CSS is also welcome.

Thanks for helping

**Updated:**

Right now I have used the CSS approach, the only problem remain is the 2nd one, that is , how to show the item line by line? Thanks

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    #footer_nav {
        float:right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you using the classes for smaller viewport sizes...are you using the media queries?

Comment: Thanks. Was using the bootstrap grid system to handle the footer. that means I need to use CSS way?

Comment: Don't use bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. would you mind have a look at the updated question? only 2nd problem left

Comment: Why don't you add the copyright line to the <ul>? ( <li><span class="copyright link">Copyright © 2006-2015 ABC Company</span></li>)

Comment: As the footer_nav part need float right but copyright line do not need?

Comment: Display: block fix the problem,  thanks